# Do WakeLocks prevent the screen from locking (password/PIN lock)? If so, can I work around that?

Tags: android, security

I have a Service that keeps the display on at a dim level at certain times, and it uses a 'dim' WakeLock to accomplish this.  It works well... except that the screen never locks.  That is, while the dim WL is held, the lock screen never appears requiring the user to swipe and authenticate.

Note that I'm developing on a platform that may have vendor changes to the low-level Android Java framework code, so this might not be standard Android behavior.  But also, I have access to the framework code and can change it, if necessary.  I just can't figure out where this policy is enforced in the code.

Comment: "Do WakeLocks prevent the screen from locking (password/PIN lock)?" -- the one you are using does. I have no idea why a `Service` would want to keep the screen on. "If so, can I work around that?" -- Use a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` for pure background work (e.g., checking for new email messages). "I have access to the framework code and can change it, if necessary. I just can't figure out where this policy is enforced in the code." -- beats me, which is why this is just a comment. That being said, you would wind up changing that for *all apps* on the device, which might not be a good idea.

Comment: When the device is on external power, we want to keep the screen contents visible - but we still want it to lock.  I would need to be able to make this somewhat configurable, as you say - basically, I need a special type of WakeLock that doesn't currently exist: a WakeLock that keeps the display on, but allows the screen to lock.

Answer (score 0):

> When the device is on external power, we want to keep the screen contents visible - but we still want it to lock.

The only way I can think of to do that is for you to maintain your own timer for when to trigger the lock, then to use `DevicePolicyManager` and `lockNow()` to lock the device at that point. This requires extra permissions and extra setup work (enabling your app as a device manager).

Comment: There's only one problem with that (I thought of this, too)... there's no public API (that I know of) for 'user activity'.  That is, my Service has no way to know when the user last did something that should restart the 'idle' timeout timer.  Do you know of a way to get this?

Comment: @cbp2: No, sorry, that's not exposed AFAIK. You can determine if the user does anything with your activities, but not in general on the system. It's obviously in the firmware somewhere, though, so if you are creating your own firmware, you might figure out some way to expose it without monkeying with the API too much (e.g., send some custom `ACTION_IDLE` broadcast).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, too.  If I'm changing the framework code, I could skin this cat a few different ways.  I'm just trying to find the least intrusive way since this code can be changed at any time by Google or the vendor... maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Can someone just tell me what the Android API is for locking the screen?  The 'sleep now' command also turns off the display, ignoring any WakeLocks - I don't want that.  I ONLY want to lock the screen, but leave the display on.

Comment: @cbp2: "Can someone just tell me what the Android API is for locking the screen?" -- um, well, there's `lockNow()` in `DevicePolicyManager`, but I pointed that out in my answer.

Comment: Yes, but that does more than lock the screen - it locks the screen and shuts off the display.  So I guess I should have been more explicit: I need a public API that locks the screen but doesn't affect the display (on, off, dim).

Comment: @cbp2: Ah, I did not realize that `lockNow()` turned off the screen. That's disappointing, as it is undocumented behavior. I doubt there is any means via the SDK of doing anything else.